# jenkins publish changes of build to confluence page

Tags: jenkins-plugins, confluence

I am using Jenkins as CI. i want to publish/append the last build's changes to confluence page. I am using Confluence Publisher Plugin to achieve this but don't know how to do.

Comment: hey @mukul did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Four years later:

1. Use https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin
2. Create a "Execute system Groovy script" build step in your job (NOT "Execute Groovy script" because this is limited to the slave node)
3. Write your changes to a file with this groovy code:

   ```
   def changeLogOut = "Bitbucket Changes:"  
   final changeSet = build.getChangeSet()  
   final changeSetIterator = changeSet.iterator()  
   while (changeSetIterator.hasNext()) {  
           final item = changeSetIterator.next()  
           changeLogOut  = changeLogOut + item.getAuthor().getFullName() +  " " +  item.getMsg()  
           for (final path : item.getPaths()) {  
           out.println path.getPath()  
       }  
   }  
   build.project.getWorkspace().child("changeset.txt").write(changeLogOut , "utf-8")
   ```
4. Use this file to publish the content with the "Publish to Confluence" plugin